# Replace all occurrences of a string within a file

Tags: string, perl, shell, operation

I have a string `test.cgi@action=<action-name>`

`<action-name>` can be any string

I would like to replace the above string with `<action-name>.html` for all the occurrences within a file.

Can any one please let me know how I can proceed with this using a Perl script?

ps: I didn't get any response when i posted as a comment to existing message. So, I'm posting as a new message.

Comment: You've been a member over a year; you need to learn how to vote, and how to accept answers.

Comment: if `<action-name>` can be any string, how do you know where the end of the string is?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a file, you could just use `sed` (assuming you're on some kind of *nix platform).

```
sed 's/test.cgi@action=/.html/g' file > output
```

or if you're feeling risky, you can edit the file in place.

```
sed -i 's/test.cgi@action=/.html/g' file
```

Comment: By using this, if i have a string test.cgi@action=self, it is replaced as ".htmlself" but i'm expecting it to replace it as "self.html". Also, How can i do this using a perl program?.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $string = <<'END_OF_STRING';
    test.cgi@action=xxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxx test.cgi@action=aaaaaa
    yyyyyyyyyyytest.cgi@action=
END_OF_STRING


$string =~ s/test.cgi\@action=/.html/g;
print $string;


--output:--
    .htmlxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxx .htmlaaaaaa
    yyyyyyyyyyy.html
```

Comment: The output which i'm expecting is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html aaaaaayyyyyyyyyy.html

Comment: Does any one know how to modify script to get my expected output.